# I want to get all of my database items

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've included this `PHP` file in my `index.php`, but I only get the first item from the database. How can I get all items from my database?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT name,price FROM items ORDER BY `id`";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<h2><?=$page["name"]?></h2>
<?=$page["price"]?>
```

Comment: you are looking for a `while` loop

Comment: or use `mysqli_fetch_all()`

Comment: You are going to need to loop over the results in order to show all the results (assuming there is more resulting row than one). If you just want to see the results without marking it up with HTML, you can just do a dump of the array (`print_r`).

Comment: Aren't there examples of this in every PHP+MySQL tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you want `all records from the database`, so you need to use `while loop` like below:-

```
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT name,price FROM items ORDER BY `id`"; // query
   $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // execute query
   while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){ // loop
      echo "<h2>". $page["name"]."</h2>".$page["price"]; // print all record (You can change pattern of printing according to your wish )
   }
   mysqli_close($conn); // close connection
?>
```

Comment: It worked for me, thank you very much ^_^

Comment: @ArevshatyanGegham  welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to loop your results that are in `$page` array. Try this:

```
<?php foreach($page as $value): ?>
    <h2><?=$value["name"]?></h2>
    <?=$value["price"]?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

if you need more info about foreach method go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: 1.`$page` is one row, not all the rows.   2. The same code is written by user1272855 and he deleted his answer, because it's wrong